# How Download from ftp server to local machine where codeigniter site is hosted in a VPS

Tags: php, ftp, codeigniter-2

I have hosted a codeigniter site in AWS which is working fine and the connection to the ftp server is also fine.

Here is my ftp class;

```
public function download_ftp($file_name) {
    $this->load->library('ftp');

    $config['hostname'] = '213.62.21.2';
    $config['username'] = 'Admin';
    $config['password'] = 'admin';
    $config['port'] = 21;
    $config['passive'] = FALSE;
    $config['debug'] = TRUE;

    $this->ftp->connect($config);

    $found_file = FALSE;
    $files = $this->ftp->list_files();
    var_dump($files);
    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach ($files as $f) {
            if ($f == './' . $file_name) {
                $found_file = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($found_file) {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Click OK to download file. You will be notified when the download is completed. Dont refresh the page until");
        </script>';

        $result = $this->ftp->download($file_name, 'C:/new/ftp/' . $file_name);
        if ($result == FALSE) {
            echo 'file not downloaded';
        }
```

**'C:/new/ftp/'** is the local directory , the file to be downloaded.

This code downloads the file to the hosted server the client accessing the website.

How to change the path so the file would be downloaded to the clent machine?

Comment: Never Post you database configuration here...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma I don't think this is real one.

Comment: See [Download a file from FTP server to client machine via website with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57878631/850848).