# Download a file from FTP server to client machine via website with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, ftp

I need download with CodeIgniter. I tried with the `force_download` function and `download` function.

With the `download` function it works, but doesn't permit select the folder for the download. With the force download function the browser downloads an empty file.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$path = file_get_contents(base_url()."modulos/".$filename); // get file name
$name = "sample_file.pdf"; // new name for your file

//

force_download($name, $path); // start download

// or

$this->ftp->download($path, '/local/path/to/'.$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

- [`$this->ftp->download`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/ftp.html#CI_FTP::download) downloads a file from an *FTP server* to a *web server*.
- [`force_download`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html#force_download) downloads a file from the *web server* to the *client*.

To download a file from the *FTP server* all the way to the the *client*, you have to combine/chain both functions.

```php
$temp_path = $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $name);
$this->ftp->download($path, $temp_path);

$data = file_get_contents($temp_path);
force_download($name, $data);
unlink($temp_path);
```